# Is there an easy way to get the number of repeating character in a word?

Tags: python, regex, string, counter

I'm trying to get how many any character repeats in a word. The repetitions must be sequential.

For example, the method with input `"loooooveee"` should return 6 (4 times 'o', 2 times 'e').

I'm trying to implement string level functions and I can do it this way but, is there an easy way to do this? Regex, or some other sort of things?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Original question: `order of repetition does not matter`

You can subtract the number of unique letters by the number of total letters. [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) applied to a string will return a unique collection of letters.

```
x = "loooooveee"
res = len(x) - len(set(x))  # 6
```

Or you can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), subtract 1 from each value, then `sum`:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter("loooooveee")

res = sum(i-1 for i in c.values())  # 6
```

#### New question: `repetitions must be sequential`

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group sequential identical characters:

```
from itertools import groupby

g = groupby("aooooaooaoo")
res = sum(sum(1 for _ in j) - 1 for i, j in g)  # 5
```

To avoid the nested `sum` calls, you can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import groupby, islice

g = groupby("aooooaooaoo")
res = sum(1 for _, j in g for _ in islice(j, 1, None))  # 5
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a regular expression if you want:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'(\w)\1+')

repeating = sum(x[1] - x[0] - 1
                for m in rx.finditer("loooooveee")
                for x in [m.span()])
print(repeating)
```

This correctly yields `6` and makes use of the `.span()` function.

---

The expression is

```
(\w)\1+
```

which captures a *word character* (one of `a-zA-Z0-9_`) and tries to repeat it as often as possible.
See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/W3zzoe/1) for the repeating pattern.

---

If you want to match any character (that is, not only word characters), change your expression to:

```
(.)\1+
```

See [**another demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/W3zzoe/3).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
word=input('something:')

sum = 0

chars=set(list(word)) #get the set of unique characters

for item in chars: #iterate over the set and output the count for each item
    if word.count(char)>1:
       sum+=word.count(char)
    print('{}|{}'.format(item,str(word.count(char)))

print('Total:'+str(sum))
```

EDIT:

added total count of repetitions

Answer (score 1):

Since it doesn't matter where the repetition is occurring or which characters are being repeated, you can make use of the `set` data structure provided in Python. It will discard the duplicate occurrences of any character or an object.

Therefore, the solution would look something like this:

```
def measure_normalized_emphasis(text):
    return len(text) - len(set(text))
```

This will give you the exact result.

Also, make sure to look out for some edge cases, which you should as it is a good practice.

Comment: I think you missed the "_The repetitions must be sequential_" part of the question.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad Ahh. The question got edited while I was answering. However, it seems that jpp has already given a clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is comparing the wrong things

You start by finding the last character:

```
char = text[-1]
```

Then you compare this to itself:

```
for i in range(1, len(text)):
    if text[-i] == char: #<-- surely this is test[-1] to begin with?
```

Why not just run through the characters:

```
def measure_normalized_emphasis(text):
    char = text[0]
    emphasis_size = 0
    for i in range(1, len(text)):
        if text[i] == char:
            emphasis_size += 1
        else:
            char = text[i]

    return emphasis_size
```

This seems to work.